# Regex : How to remove XML tag style

Tags: php, regex

I have a config.ini file formed as XML like that :

```
<positions>

    <position>
        <name>BLOCK TAB 1</name>
        <tag>[BLOCK_TAB_1]</tag>
    </position>


    <position>
        <name>PERSONALAREA</name>
        <tag>[PERSONALAREA]</tag>
    </position>
</positions>
```

I tried to remove the block :

```
<position>
    <name>BLOCK TAB 1</name>
    <tag>[BLOCK_TAB_1]</tag>
</position>
```

by using preg_replace

```
$find1 = "/<name>BLOCK TAB 1<\/name>/";
$find2 = "/<tag>\[BLOCK_TAB_1\]<\/tag>/";

$contents = preg_replace($find1, "", $contents);
$contents = preg_replace($find2, "", $contents);
```

But the content will be

```
<positions>

    <position>


    </position>


    <position>
        <name>PERSONALAREA</name>
        <tag>[PERSONALAREA]</tag>
    </position>
</positions>
```

The empty `<position>` tag ( with tabs inside ) still here.

Try to use `/<position[^>]*><\\/position[^>]*>/` to replace empty `<position>` tag, but because of tabs inside, so replace is not working.

Somebody have idea ?

Comment: ' "<position>\n\s+<name>BLOCK TAB 1</name>\n\s+<tag>\[BLOCK_TAB_1\]</tag>\n\s+</position>" ' use this or                                    ' "<position>\n\s+<name>.*</name>\n\s+<tag>.*</tag>\n\s+</position>" '

Comment: @Ashish Thanks you! I tried but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You shouldn't use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to parse this XML. In this example, you could use XPath to easily identify the `<name>` that has the text "BLOCK TAB 1", then select its parent and remove it:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$positions = $xpath->query('//name[text()="BLOCK TAB 1"]/parent::position');

foreach ($positions as $position) {
    // Remove it
    $position->parentNode->removeChild($position);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

<kbd>[Example](https://eval.in/553688)</kbd>

Comment: yup, no to regex, this is the proper tool to use

Comment: Thank you ! I have a little trouble with DOMDocument and simpleXML : My text is in Vietnamese and after parse, it will be come like this ``` &#x110;&#xE2;y l&#xE0; giao di&#x1EC7;n m&#x1EB7;c &#x111;&#x1ECB;nh c&#x1EE7;a h&#x1EC7;  ```

Comment: You will need to set the appropriate encoding when you call DOMDocument

Comment: @RobbieAverill Tried  
```$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');```

Still no luck.

Comment: Ah, Fixed with ```html_entity_decode``` before export to file. Thank you, again.